# What is website page performance when input controls exceed high?

Tags: asp.net

I have requirement in website, where i need to provide around 60 textbox inside form.

I woud like to know whether it make performance down when i put such large count of textbox (60) in form.

Is there any alternate way to meet this requirement.

Please help?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about performance, but it'll be a nuisance to fill in and you may start to run into timeout issues with session etc.

Have you considered breaking the page up into sections and serving different pages in a wizard style control?